# How to use sql NOT operator in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a simple table with an int[] column and I would like to be able to select rows that do not contain a specified user. And I can't figure out how to do it with SQLAlchemy. I could easily make a request in SQL: `SELECT * FROM practices WHERE not (33 = any(id_user))` but have no idea how to do it using `Practice.query.filter(...)`

Here is the schema for the table ("practices"):

```
Column        |          Type          |
--------------+------------------------+
 id           | integer                |
 some_data    | character varying(250) |
 id_user      | integer[]              |
```

Here is what it looks like with sample data:

```
 id |  some_data   |    id_user
----+--------------+---------------
  1 | ------       | {25,33,42,55}
  2 | ------       | {11,33,7,19}
  3 | ------       | {32,6,20,23}
  4 | ------       | {19,33,27,8}
  5 | ------       | {25,33,10,40}
  6 | ------       | {25,33,40,39}
  7 | ------       | {1,20,18,38}
```

After i run my query i want to see this:

```
id |  some_data   |    id_user
----+--------------+---------------
  3 | ------       | {32,6,20,23}
  7 | ------       | {1,20,18,38}
```

Here is the Python code I used to generate the table:

```
class Practice(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "practices"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    id_user = Column(ARRAY(Integer))
    some_data = Column(String(255))

    def __init__(self, id_user, some_data):
        self.id_user = id_user
        self.id_coach = id_coach
        self.id_coach = some_data

    def details(self):
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'id_users': self.id_user,
            'some_data': self.some_data
        }

    def insert(self):
        db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()

    def delete(self):
        db.session.delete(self)
        db.session.commit()

    def update(self):
        db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
query(Practice).filter(~Practice.id_user.contains([33])).all()
```

Comment: This won't work because id_user type not integer. It's array of integer

Comment: And again, this does not do what I described in the problem. It finds all occurrences of user with id=33 in the array. And I need to find all arrays where there is no user with this id. The main problem is that I can't find the implementation of the "NOT" method in sqlalchemy

Comment: I have tried this option. It returns all the records from the table

Comment: Again types error. `integer[] <> integer`

Comment: Error again. I'm starting to think it's just not possible and NOT operator not implement in sqlalchemy

Comment: which version of sqlalchemy are you using?

Comment: i use version = 1.3.16

Comment: damn it, it finally works. the problem was in the old version. After updating to version 1.4.36 everything works. it was only necessary to change `postgre://` to `postgresql://` in the database connection module. Thanks for the help. I would never have thought to check the version of sqlalchemy